# Is it possible to log via the Flink Python API

Tags: apache-flink

I've looked at the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/batch/python.html), sample code and the user groups but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All output to stdout will be forwarded to the Flink .out logs. This means that you can insert debugging print() statements.

There is nothing currently that supports writing log messages into the .log files.

Comment: Thanks, this works, though not as useful as log4j etc

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported. You can use the standard logging library or `print`. For example:

```py
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.BIGINT())
def add(i, j):
    # use logging modules
    import logging
    logging.info("debug")
    # use print function
    print('debug')
    return i + j
```

It's referenced in the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/debugging/#logging-infos) as well.